# Page will not load and I get a "Newtown.json" warning message

Tags: c#, charts, chart.js

I am adding a line chart, with styles (Line-styles-chart), to my project and when I run it, the page does not load. I just get an image of the loading cursor.  In visual studio 2019, I get the following warning message:

```
   "Found conflicts between versions of "Newtonsoft.Json" that could not be resolved. These references are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
```

Does Anybody know why I am getting this? I have the latest version of newtown.json

Inside my packagesconfig I have it set up like this, with the latest Newtonsoft.json.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets" version="14.0.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="4.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

This is how I have my script.js set up:

```
$(function () {
    new Chart(document.getElementById("line_chart").getContext("2d"), getChartJs('line'));
    new Chart(document.getElementById("bar_chart").getContext("2d"), getChartJs('bar'));
    new Chart(document.getElementById("line_styles_Chart").getContext("2d"), getChartJs('line-styles'));
});

function getChartJs(type) {
    var config = null;

    if (type === 'line') {
        config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ["Groceries", "Rent", "Utilities", "Student Loans", "Car payment"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Refund",
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 45, 56],
                    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.75)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.3)',
                    pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0)',
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.9)',
                    pointBorderWidth: 1
                }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: false
            }

        }
    }
    else if (type === 'bar') {
        config = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Gas bill", "light bill", "Rent", "Cell phone bill", "Water Bill", "Groceries", "Spotify"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.8)'
                }, {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.8)'
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: false
            }
        }
    }
    else if (type === 'line-styles') {
        var config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Gas bill',
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.8)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                    data: [0, 42, 55],
                }, {
                    label: 'Light bill',
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.8)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                    borderDash: [5, 5],
                    data: [28, 48, 40],
                }, {
                    label: 'Rent',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 209, 0, 0.8)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
                    data: [40, 27, 90],
                    fill: true,
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Line Styles Chart'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false,
                },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'nearest',
                    intersect: true
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Month'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Value'
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        };
    }
    return config;
}
```

This is how I have it set up in my html:

```
  <div class="report-card">
        <p class="text-center p-t-20 text-muted">Monthly expenses</p>
        <canvas id="line_chart" height="150"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="report-card">
        <p class="text-center p-t-20 text-muted">Monthly expenses</p>
        <canvas id="bar_chart" height="150"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="report-card">
        <p class="text-center p-t-20 text-muted">Monthly expenses</p>
        <canvas id="line_styles_Chart" height="150"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Comment: One of those dependencies probably requires a specific version of Newtonsoft. Your app is using 6.0.4 which is 5 years old...

Comment: @DavidG   IS there a way to upgrade it to the current version?

Comment: I would comb the dependencies for your packages in NuGet package manager and determine where the difference lies in versions of Newtonsoft and standardize your direct dependency of Newtonsoft with the other package's dependency version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All references are old, I think it would be nice to go to the nuget package manager and update the references, for example you use version 6.0.4 of Json.NET and the latest version is 12.0.2

> https://www.newtonsoft.com/json
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client/